# Troubleshooting data inconsistencies with Python multiprocessing/threading

Tags: python, multithreading, solr, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

TL;DR: Getting different results after running code with threading and multiprocessing and single threaded. Need guidance on troubleshooting.

Hello, I apologize in advance if this may be a bit too generic, but I need a bit of help troubleshooting an issue and I am not sure how best to proceed.

Here is the story; I have a bunch of data indexed into a Solr Collection (~250m items), all items in that collection have a sessionid. Some items can share the same session id. I am combing through the collection to extract all items that have the same session, massage the data a bit and spit out another JSON file for indexing later.

The code has two main functions: 
proc_day - accepts a day and processes all the sessions for that day
and
proc_session - does everything that needs to happen for a single session.

Multiprocessing is implemented on proc_day, so each day would be processed by a separate process, the proc_session function can be ran with threads. Below is the code I am using for threading/multiprocessing below. It accepts a function, a list of arguments and number of threads / multiprocesses. It will then create a queue based on input args, then create processes/threads and let them go through it. I am not posting the actual code, since it generally runs fine single threaded without any issues, but can post it if needed.

autoprocs.py

```
import sys
import logging
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue,JoinableQueue
import time
import multiprocessing
import os

def proc_proc(func,data,threads,delay=10):
    if threads < 0:
        return
    q = JoinableQueue()
    procs = []

    for i in range(threads):
        thread = Process(target=proc_exec,args=(func,q))
        thread.daemon = True;
        thread.start()
        procs.append(thread)

    for item in data:
        q.put(item)

    logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + ' *** Processes started and data loaded into queue waiting')

    s = q.qsize()
    while s > 0:
        logging.info(str(os.getpid()) + " - Proc Queue Size is:" + str(s))
        s = q.qsize()
        time.sleep(delay)

    for p in procs:
        logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + " - Joining Process {}".format(p))
        p.join(1)

    logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + ' - *** Main Proc waiting')
    q.join()
    logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + ' - *** Done')

def proc_exec(func,q):
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + ' - Starting:{},{}'.format(p.name, p.pid))
    while True:
        d = q.get()
        try:
            logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + " - Starting to Process {}".format(d))
            func(d)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + " - Marking Task as Done")
            q.task_done()
        except:
            logging.error(str(os.getpid()) + " - Exception in subprocess execution")
            logging.error(sys.exc_info()[0])
    logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + 'Ending:{},{}'.format(p.name, p.pid))
```

autothreads.py:

```
import threading
import logging
import time
from queue import Queue

def thread_proc(func,data,threads):
    if threads < 0:
        return "Thead Count not specified"
    q = Queue()

    for i in range(threads):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_exec,args=(func,q))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    for item in data:
        q.put(item)

    logging.debug('*** Main thread waiting')
    s = q.qsize()
    while s > 0:
        logging.debug("Queue Size is:" + str(s))
        s = q.qsize()
        time.sleep(1)
    logging.debug('*** Main thread waiting')
    q.join()
    logging.debug('*** Done')

def thread_exec(func,q):
    while True:
        d = q.get()
        #logging.debug("Working...")
        try:
            func(d)
        except:
            pass
        q.task_done()
```

I am running into problems with validating data after python runs under different multiprocessing/threading configs. There is a lot of data, so I really need to get multiprocessing working. Here are the results of my test yesterday.

```
Only with multiprocessing - 10 procs: 
Days Processed  30
Sessions Found  3,507,475 
Sessions Processed 3,514,496 
Files 162,140 
Data Output: 1.9G

multiprocessing and multithreading - 10 procs 10 threads
Days Processed  30
Sessions Found   3,356,362 
Sessions Processed   3,272,402 
Files    424,005 
Data Output: 2.2GB

just threading - 10 threads
Days Processed  31
Sessions Found   3,595,263 
Sessions Processed   3,595,263 
Files    733,664 
Data Output: 3.3GB

Single process/ no threading
Days Processed  31
Sessions Found   3,595,263 
Sessions Processed   3,595,263 
Files    162,190 
Data Output: 1.9GB
```

These counts were gathered by grepping and counties entries in the log files (1 per main process). The first thing that jumps out is that days processed doesn't match. However, I manually checked the log files and it looks like a log entry was missing, there are follow on log entries to indicate that the day was actually processed. I have no idea why it was omitted.

I really don't want to write more code to validate this code, just seems like a terrible waste of time, is there any alternative?

Comment: I think people will help, but just a comment regarding: *"I really don't want to write more code to validate this code, just seems like a terrible waste of time"*: if that data analysis is important, then you better make 100 % sure that your processing pipeline works the way to intend it to work. Corresponding testing code may easily be more complex than the code you are testing.

Comment: "Sessions Found   3,595,263 , Sessions Processed   3,595,263 " -- is that the expected output? Meaning, do "single process / no threading" and "just threading - 10 threads" work as expected? What is "Files 162,140 , Data Output: 1.9G"? Do these numbers describe input or output? Is that important for us?

Comment: Just a warning: `if threads < 0: return "Thead Count not specified"` alone does not really make people want to debug your code. A negative number means "not specified"? In the Python world, that is semantic B$. Not providing an argument gives you a nice exception, by default. And returning an error message as a string? So, you specified this function return value to be either `None` or an error message? You really should dig into Python exceptions before trying to implement complex concurrency constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave some general hints in the comments above. I think there are multiple problems with your approach, at very different levels of abstraction. You are also not showing all code of relevance.

The issue might very well be

1. in the method you are using to read from solr or in preparing read data before feeding it to your workers.
2. in the architecture you have come up with for distributing the work among multiple processes.
3. in your logging infrastructure (as you have pointed out yourself).
4. in your analysis approach.

You *have to* go through all of these points, and as of the complexity of the issue surely nobody here will be able to identify the exact issues for you.

### Regarding points (3) and (4):

If you are not sure about the completeness of your log files, you should perform the analysis based on the payload output of your processing engine. What I am trying to say: the log files probably are just a side product of your data processing. The primary product is the thing you should analyze. Of course it is also important to get your logs right. But these two problems should be treated independently.

### My contribution regarding point (2) in the list above:

What is especially suspicious about your `multiprocessing`-based solution is your way to *wait* for the workers to finish. You seem not to be sure by which method you should wait for your workers, so you apply three different methods:

**First**, you are monitoring the size of the queue in a while loop and wait for it to become 0. This is a non-canonical approach, which might actually work.

**Secondly**, you `join()` your processes in a weird way:

```
for p in procs:
    logging.debug(str(os.getpid()) + " - Joining Process {}".format(p))
    p.join(1)
```

Why are you defining a timeout of one second here and do not respond to whether the process actually terminated within that time frame? You should either really join a process, i.e. wait until it *has terminated* or you specify a timeout and, if that timeout expires before the process finishes, treat that situation specially. Your code does not distinguish these situations, so `p.join(1)` is like writing `time.sleep(1)` instead.

**Thirdly**, you join the queue.

So, after making sure that `q.qsize()` returns 0 and after waiting for another second, do you really think that joining the queue is important? Does it make any difference? *One* of these approaches should be enough, and you need to think about which of these criteria is most important to your problem. That is, one of these conditions should *deterministically implicate* the other two.

All this looks like a quick & dirty hack of a multiprocessing solution, whereas you yourself are not really sure how that solution should behave. One of the most important insights I have obtained while working on concurrency architectures: You, the architect, must be 100 % aware of how the communication and control flow works in your system. Not properly monitoring and controlling the state of your worker processes may very well be the source of the issues you are observing.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I followed Jan-Philip's advice and started examining the output data of the multiprocess/multithreaded process. Turned out that an object that does all these things with the data from Solr was shared among threads. I did not have any locking mechanisms, so in a case it had mixed data from multiple sessions which caused inconsistent output. I validated this by instantiating a new object for every thread and the counts matched up. It is a bit slower, but still workable.

Thanks